# В ListView, onClick на текст срабатывает со второго нажатия

Tags: java, android, listview, textview, android-on-click

Предыстория: Есть ListView, в нем TextView где находятся URL-ссылки. Чтобы было удобней выбирать какую ссылку нажать, используется PopUpMenu. Вызывается оно через
`onClickListener`, вот таким образом -
 `view.findViewById(R.id.textView105).setOnClickListener(UrlLinks);`.

Проблема:`onClickListener` всегда срабатывает со второго нажатия.

Вопрос: Какие могут быть этому причины?

Comment: Промахиваетесь? :D Попробуйте логировать нажатия. А вдруг и правда

Comment: Логи - неотъемлемая часть моего кода. И размеры textView позволяют промахнуться только корове, которая будет тыкать копытом. :D. Плюс ко всему я отслеживаю касания. Так что этот вариант - точно не причина.

Comment: Вопросы с просьбами помочь с отладкой (**«почему этот код не работает?»**) должны включать желаемое поведение, конкретную проблему или ошибку и минимальный код для её воспроизведения **прямо в вопросе**. Вопросы без **явного описания проблемы** бесполезны для остальных посетителей. См. [Как создать минимальный, самодостаточный и воспроизводимый пример.](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Проблема в коде. Но вы его не показали. Надо показать.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Возможно Вам поможет следующее, установите в TextView

```
android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
```

Подсмотрел у англоязычных коллег:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42470001/edittext-inside-textinputlayout-onclick-requires-2-click-android

Comment: Роман, Вы правы! Не совсем конечно, но ... в моем случае получилось что атрибут focusable и значение "false" сыграло свою роль. Сделайте правку ответа и получите галочку )))